# Clover and Bamboo Purging old Builds

Tags: bamboo, clover

Does anyone know how I can configure bamboo to purge it's old builds. I have clover running and my server has just run out of space. I have discovered that for each build the clover directory is about 100 MB. It's full of all the code coverage reports. It would be good to have perhaps the last 10 clover reports but I don't need all of them. Can I get Bamboo to purge it's old builds?

As it is not purging the bamboo-data directory gets bigger and bigger and bigger each time it builds. (which happens many times a day)

On my machine this directory contains loads of build files.
/usr/local/bamboo-data/artifacts/PROJECT_NAME/JOB1/build....

I could just create a script that runs under cron to do the delete but it seems like this should be common problem so I'd like an Atlassian base solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have figured this out. In the build configuration there is a Build Expiry option. According to the Atlassian docs I can enable this to delete old artifacts and test result. I have set it in my build and will see what happens when it is time to run.